# How a Service can call an Activity? Official example does not work!

Tags: android, service, notifications

I tried to play with the Service. Now, a service is running, ... it adds notification on task bar. When task bar is clicked, this notification should call MyActivity.class.
But it gives error. Please see the code, after the error,
Error:

> ... W/dalvikvm( 2384): threadid=1:
>   thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x4001d7e0) E/AndroidRuntime(
>   2384): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2384):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   start activity
>   ComponentInfo{activity.change/activity.change.MyActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> ....

Code:

```
public void addNotification()
    {

    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);


    int icon = R.drawable.icon; //.drawable.notification_icon;
    CharSequence tickerText = "Hello";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
    //notification.defaults=Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE+Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    //notification.defaults=notification.flags
    notification.flags|=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;


    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence contentTitle = "UHS Next";
    CharSequence contentText = "Hello World!";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Class_B.class); // I want to call class_B, not A. A has called "this" Service though.
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    /*
     * PendingIntent mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(AlarmService.this, 0, new Intent(AlarmService.this, AlarmService_Service.class), 0);
     * */

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);


    //private static final int HELLO_ID = 1;  << moved to the global declaration 
    mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);

}
```

`// Part of error log`:

```
I/WindowManager(   90): Ignoring HOME; event canceled.
D/MyService( 5206): Received message!!
D/dalvikvm(   90): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 22585 objects / 1120256 bytes in 79ms
D/dalvikvm( 5206): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3702 objects / 224088 bytes in 77ms
I/ActivityManager(   90): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN 
    cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 
    cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher }
D/dalvikvm(  172): GC_EXPLICIT freed 36 objects / 1944 bytes in 91ms
I/ActivityManager(   90): Starting activity: 
    Intent { cmp=activity.change/.W2PExampleAndNew bnds=[0,387][480,483] }
W/ActivityManager(   90): startActivity called from non-Activity context; 
    forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: 
    Intent { cmp=activity.change/.W2PExampleAndNew bnds=[0,387][480,483] }
V/RenderScript_jni(  171): surfaceDestroyed
D/AndroidRuntime( 5206): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 5206): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7e0)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5206): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 5206): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
    {activity.change/activity.change.W2PExampleAndNew}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 5206):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5206):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5206):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5206):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5206):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5206):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5206):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5206):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5206):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5206):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5206):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5206):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5206): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 5206):    at activity.change.W2PExampleAndNew.onCreate(W2PExampleAndNew.java:63)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5206):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5206):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5206):    ... 11 more
W/ActivityManager(   90):   Force finishing activity activity.change/.W2PExampleAndNew
W/ActivityManager(   90): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{44cafc20 activity.change/.W2PExampleAndNew}
V/RenderScript_jni(  171): surfaceCreated
V/RenderScript_jni(  171): surfaceChanged
D/WifiService(   90): acquireWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NetworkLocationProvider type=2 binder=android.os.Binder@44d28380}
D/LocationMasfClient(   90): getNetworkLocation(): Returning cache location with accuracy 70.0
D/dalvikvm(  465): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6095 objects / 509112 bytes in 38ms
W/ActivityManager(   90): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{44cafc20 activity.change/.W2PExampleAndNew}
D/WifiService(   90): releaseWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NetworkLocationProvider type=2 binder=android.os.Binder@44d28380}
I/Process ( 5206): Sending signal. PID: 5206 SIG: 9
W/InputManagerService(   90): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: 
    com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44d18b80
I/ActivityManager(   90): Process activity.change (pid 5206) has died.
W/ActivityManager(   90): Scheduling restart of crashed service activity.change/.W2PAndroidService in 5000ms
I/ActivityManager(   90): Start proc activity.change for service activity.change/.W2PAndroidService: pid=5258 uid=10073 gids={1006, 1015, 3003}
D/MyService( 5258): onCreate
```

Comment: The error message says you have a NullPointerException in your Activity, and you posted the code from the service.  I'm not surprised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure, that you have the `MyActivity` activity declared in your `androidManifest.xml`.

**Update**
If `MyActivity` is your main launcher activity (which starts the service), and you want to start `Activity_B` from your notification, then both of these activities must be declared in your `androidManifest.xml` (watch for the `launchMode`, if you set any!):

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="Activity_B" />
```

Also, the `Intent` when specifying your notification should look like:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Activity_B.class);
```

**Depr.**
You could also try setting `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this` when creating the `PendingIntent`:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried with both, "this" in notification and pending content, and getAppliocationContext, instead of "this", yet no luck, says, "startactivity called from non-activity context" :(

Comment: Would you please share your `androidManifest.xml` as well? thank you.

Comment: @rekaszeru, thank you very much. Now I can tell you the whats the problem at my side. It works fine with "this" for the Activity that started the Service.
Example:

Class_A{call Service_My_service}

Then, Service_My_service can call the Class_A when I clicked the notification.

But, actually I need to call Class_B, NOT Class_A. 
Class_A and Class_B are in the same package!

Any idea?

Thanks much for your time!

Comment: when constructing your `Notification`, you should declare the `Intent` for the `PendingIntent` instance as: Intent `notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Class_B.class);`, Class_B being the activity that will be started when user clicks on the notification. Please see my update.

Comment: Hello,
Sorry but the result is the same.

Comment: Which line of code gives you the exception? would you share the stack trace (from logcat/ddms), please?

Comment: Hello,
Thanks much. But,
sorry but the result is the same.

A.
1. Manifest is OK, I can call A from B, B from A.

B.
2. Intent in the service is OK, I called Class_B from the service.

And got this error,
"unable to start activity componentInfo{activity.change/activity.change.Actvity_B} : jana.lang.NullPointerExp...."

My classes are in activity.change path.

Any other clue?

Comment: Where does the NPE point? please don't cut off that part of the stack, it supposed to say where you have a null-instance.

Comment: Hmm..probably I my experience does not allow me to understand what you mean. Please excuse me... here is a part of error msg, in the error "W2PExample..." this is my Class_B!

this is the link to the error!
http://imageshare.web.id/images/67068p0dcl8igwov1m6.jpg

Comment: I have this W2PExample..(Class_B lest call it B!) class in the manifest, I can call it from Class_A, and B can also call A vice versa.

This service works fine if I call, Class_A from it! (Which I dont want)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see any image there, but a login-page is shown up. What I meant, was: please paste the rest of the error message: "`java.lang.NullPointerExpception` at line..." what comes after? It points you to the line where the problem is (or the `Caused by` clause will), so the full stack trace would be very useful to track down this error. You should paste it into your question by editing it, not in the comment (it is not readable here). Also the manifest xml might help.

Comment: This site does not allow to post long text,
http://www.sendspace.com/file/4tb3we
Full log,
http://www.sendspace.com/file/0kuw5c

Editing? Oh, now I understand.. :)

Comment: These links force me to download an exe, which i really don't want. Could you please just edit your question, and append the log? thank you

Comment: I see..! This is strange. I am sorry for that. Now, I have edited the question and added the error.

Comment: The error says, that the error is in your `W2PExampleAndNew.java` class, on line #63; so there something has a null value. What do you have in that line?

Comment: I don't know how can I thank you!
Thank you very very much! It was a Bundle that I did not check whether it was null or not!
Thank you buddy!